# Trying to create and access network shared folders on a Ubuntu desktop in VMware from a Windows machine

Tags: networking, server, samba, vmware

[Windows Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHZ0v.png)New here and tried my best to search for this answer.Been a while since I worked with Linux shares

I am trying to create an Ubuntu desktop on a VMware (Win 19 Server host OS).
This is setup and working however following the share tutorials with nautilus showing right click share folder.

https://itsfoss.com/share-folders-local-network-ubuntu-windows/

However when trying to access from win machine I get access authentication errors. Do I need to open something in the VM? I am not trying to have the VM share down to the host OS just a network share. In essence a desktop file server

Ubuntu 22

Thank you

Comment: Ubuntu 22 means you are running Ubuntu Core 22 the only version of Ubuntu to use a single digit version number. If this is not correct please edit the question and put in the correct version info.

Comment: This ^^^and I assume you're using 22.04 or 22.10 because you mentioned "desktop". Now, for starters, shared folders in a VM is typically managed by the hypervisor, the virtualization software (VMware): https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-D6D9A5FD-7F5F-4C95-AFAB-EDE9335F5562.html

Comment: Yes, I am running 22.04 desktop I have another win 10 machine on this VMware workstaion and I share just fine so this shouldn't be the VMware I am using Workstation 15.5. Sharing means network share not meaing allowing the VM to access the host type share.